# Concat a single file to every file in a directory using grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

Using Grunt, I want to concat one file to all of the files in a build directory. The purpose of doing so is to append (or potentially prepend) IE specific CSS files to a build CSS file.

To task this:

```
build/
  file1.css
  file2.css
  file3.css
```

And create this:

```
build/
  file1.css
  file1.ie.css
  file2.css
  file2.ie.css
  file3.css
  file3.ie.css
```

I thought that the expand option might be what I was looking for but I can't figure out how to get it to do what I want.

Comment: how are you determining which files get concatenated together? Also, where in the structure of your app/site is the IE specific file?

Comment: The ie specific file sits next to the build dir, in a css directory. I want to append the ie file to all of the files in the build directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `banner` option in `grunt-contrib-concat`:

```
concat: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      banner: '/* IE specific things here */',
    },
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'build/',
    ext: '.ie.css',
    src: ['**/*.css'],
    dest: 'build/',
  },
},
```

Comment: Ah, great idea! ``footer`` might also be a great choice.